# Getting output of Async SAPI call?

Tags: c++, windows, text-to-speech, sapi

I have a working example using the Windows text-to-speech API, but the problem is it freezes when given a large amount of text.

To solve this I want to make the process asynchronous. I've found the `SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags::SVSFlagsAsync` flag, but **how do I get the results of a previously-submitted request?**

Here is my code:

```
char* TextToWavInner( const wchar_t* voiceRequiredAttributes, const wchar_t* voiceOptionalAttributes, long rate, const wchar_t* textToRender, ULONG* pBytesRead )
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CComPtr<ISpVoice> cpVoice; //Will send data to ISpStream
    CComPtr<ISpStream> cpStream; //Will contain IStream
    CComPtr<IStream> cpBaseStream; //raw data
    ISpObjectToken* cpToken( NULL ); //Will set voice characteristics
    
    GUID guidFormat;
    WAVEFORMATEX* pWavFormatEx = nullptr;
    
    hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_SpVoice );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return NULL;
    
    hr = SpFindBestToken( SPCAT_VOICES, voiceRequiredAttributes, voiceOptionalAttributes, &cpToken );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return NULL;
    
    hr = cpVoice->SetVoice( cpToken );
    cpToken->Release();
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return NULL;
    
    cpVoice->SetRate( rate );
    
    hr = cpStream.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_SpStream );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return NULL;
    
    hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal( NULL, true, &cpBaseStream );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return NULL;
    
    hr = SpConvertStreamFormatEnum( SPSF_44kHz16BitMono, &guidFormat, &pWavFormatEx );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return NULL;
    
    hr = cpStream->SetBaseStream( cpBaseStream, guidFormat, pWavFormatEx );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return NULL;
    
    hr = cpVoice->SetOutput( cpStream, false );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return NULL;
    
    SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags voiceFlags = ( SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags ) ( SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags::SVSFlagsAsync | SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags::SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak );
    hr = cpVoice->Speak( textToRender, voiceFlags, NULL );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return NULL;
    
    LARGE_INTEGER a = { 0 };
    hr = cpStream->Seek( a, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
        return NULL;
    
    STATSTG stats;
    cpStream->Stat( &stats, STATFLAG_NONAME );
    
    ULONG sSize = stats.cbSize.LowPart;
    
    char* pBuffer = new char[ sSize ];
    cpStream->Read( pBuffer, sSize, pBytesRead );
    return pBuffer;
}
```

Comment: `ISpVoice::WaitUntilDone`?

Comment: You need to set up an event sink.  SAPI will fire an event when synthesis completes.